# can't create the last two tables in my MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database

Please also help me in finding errors in my ER Model ( I'm not allowed to have more than 6 tables)

[image]

```
CREATE DATABASE DIVIGN;

USE DIVIGN;

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER (10) PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR (32),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR (32),
PASSWORD VARCHAR (16),
ADDRESS VARCHAR  (100),
COUNTRY VARCHAR (32),
AGE INTEGER (3),
GENDER CHAR (1),
EMAIL_ADDRESS VARCHAR  (32),
PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR(10));

CREATE TABLE SELLER
(SELLER_ID INTEGER (10) PRIMARY KEY,
FIRST_NAME VARCHAR (32),
LAST_NAME VARCHAR (32),
PASSWORD VARCHAR (16),
ADDRESS VARCHAR (100),
COUNTRY VARCHAR (32),
EMAIL_ADDRESS VARCHAR  (32),
PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR (10));

CREATE TABLE ARTWORK
(ARTWORK_ID INTEGER (10) PRIMARY KEY,
SELLER_ID INTEGER (10),
NAME VARCHAR (32),
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (120),
CATEGORY VARCHAR (32),
PRICE INTEGER (10),
QUANTITY_AVAILABLE INTEGER (10),
KEYWORDS VARCHAR (100),
CONSTRAINT FK_SiD FOREIGN KEY (SELLER_ID) REFERENCES SELLER (SELLER_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE ORDER
(ORDER_ID INTEGER (10) PRIMARY KEY,
CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER (10),
ORDER_DATE DATE,
PAYPAL_ADDRESS VARCHAR (10),
SHIPPING_ADDRESS VARCHAR (100),
SHIPPING_COUNTRY VARCHAR (32),
SHIPPED_DATE DATE,
COMPLETED VARCHAR (16),
CONSTRAINT FK_CiD FOREIGN KEY (CUSTOMER_ID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (CUSTOMER_ID)
);                      

CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAIL
(ORDER_ID INTEGER (10),
ARTWORK_ID INTEGER (10),
SELLER_ID INTEGER (10),
PRICE INTEGER (10),
QUANTITY INTEGER (10),
CONSTRAINT FK_OiD FOREIGN KEY (ORDER_ID) REFERENCES ORDER (ORDER_ID)
CONSTRAINT FK_AiD FOREIGN KEY (ARTWORK_ID) REFERENCES ARTWORK (ARTWORK_ID)
CONSTRAINT FK_SiD FOREIGN KEY (SELLER_ID) REFERENCES SELLER (SELLER_ID)
);
```

Comment: `ORDER` is a SQL keyword and MySQL reserved word.  I would suggest naming all tables in the plural (ie. "ORDERS" rather than "ORDER", "SELLERS" rather than "SELLER").  Many fewer reserved words are plurals.

Comment: Thank you i was able to create the 'ORDER' table but still can't create the last one..

Comment: . . Fix the foreign key reference.  By the way, I vote to close these questions.  It is pretty obvious that `ORDER` is a reserved word, because it is a common SQL keyword.

Comment: Do you mean this Fix? ORDER TO ORDERS ...but i. still can't create the table

Comment: i am not able to fix the second and third foreign key reference (ARTWORK_ID & SELLER_ID) in the last table

Comment: Well, does it reference ORDER or ORDERS?

Comment: it references 'ORDERS' now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer that Foreign Key names should be unique across tables...I've used a foreign key name that had already been used in the last table.